# Relative paths in properties file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jersey, jersey-client

How to configure properties file in Eclipse java?

How can we provide relative addresses in the properties file?

These two lines are working

```
modelsPath=C:\\Users\\rishika.shrivastava\\workspace\\CSVWEB\\src\\com\\models

csvFilePath=c:/users/rishika.shrivastava/workspace/CSVWEB/
```

But when i use relative addresses like this:

```
modelsPath=/CSVWEB\\src\\com\\models

csvFilePath=/CSVWEB/
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: For the relative paths you are assuming the current directory is the workspace directory - which is probably not the case.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, in JBOSS, I have to reference a JKS file inside a properties file that are in the class path. When I use the absolute path, it works otherwise it doesn't ! (Same behavior in WIN and in LINUX)

Answer (score 0):

If your files are to be resource on the classpath, then you should read them as resources, not as files on the file system, (which is what happens when you use `File` or a `FileXxx` variant).

To read resources from the classpath, you could do

```
getClass().getResource("/com/models/file")
```

Or if you need an `InputStream` you can do

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/models/file")
```

**Some Resources**

- [`Class` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) to see what those methods do
- [How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1464291/2587435)